# Different unique token for the different instances of same page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of devices with device Id. On right clicking each device, it will pass device Id and open same page in multiple tabs(on each right click same page in new tab) with corresponding details of clicked device.

And here I have to keep a different token(random string variable) for each tab. And also token should not be changed on page refresh.
How can I do this ? I tried something but it's not working.

Created a random string, appended device Id to it and stored in local Storage as,

```
var prToken = window.localStorage.getItem('token');
        if(prToken){
            var subString = prToken.substring(10, prToken.length);
            if(subString == GlobalVar.Inventory.device.id){
                console.log(window.localStorage.getItem('token')+"====token");
            }else{
                var rString = GlobalVar.Inventory.randomString(10, '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',GlobalVar.Inventory.device.id);
                window.localStorage.setItem('token', rString);
            }

        }else{
            var rString = GlobalVar.Inventory.randomString(10, '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',GlobalVar.Inventory.device.id);
            window.localStorage.setItem('token', rString);
        }
```

here I am getting different token for each tab, but the problem is that, token is changing on page refresh.

Need help.

Comment: Check if a token already exists - if it does, don't make a new one...

Comment: If two tabs are opened say T1 and T2, when I go to T1 and refreshed it, will get the same token. Then I go to T2, then come back to T1, then the earlier token is not retained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved myself, and it's working fine for me.

I

> replaced 'token' variable with the device Id

. Then everything worked fine.
Then the code will be,

```
    var prToken = window.localStorage.getItem(GlobalVar.Inventory.device.id);
            if(prToken){
                var subString = prToken.substring(10, prToken.length);
                if(subString == GlobalVar.Inventory.device.id){
                    console.log(window.localStorage.getItem(GlobalVar.Inventory.device.id)+"====token");
                }else{
                    var rString = GlobalVar.Inventory.randomString(10, '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',GlobalVar.Inventory.device.id);
                    window.localStorage.setItem(GlobalVar.Inventory.device.id, rString);
                }

            }else{
                var rString = GlobalVar.Inventory.randomString(10, '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',GlobalVar.Inventory.device.id);
                window.localStorage.setItem(GlobalVar.Inventory.device.id, rString);
            }
```